# THREE JS Imported Model Size and Performance

Tags: three.js, 3d

I was hoping to display in my app as many as 3,000 instances of the same model at the same time  - but it’s really slowing down my computer. It's just too much.

I know `InstancedMesh` is the way to go for something like this so I’ve been following THREE.js’s examples here: https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/objects/InstancedMesh

The examples are fantastic, but they seem to use really small models which makes it really hard to get a good feel for what the model size-limits should be.

For example:
-The Spheres used [here](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_instancing_raycast) aren't imported custom 3D models, they're just instances of [IcosahedronGeometry](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/geometries/IcosahedronGeometry)
-The `Flower.glb` model used in [this example](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_instancing_scatter) is tiny: it only has 218 Vertices on it.
-And the “Flying Monkeys” [here](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_instancing_performance) come from a **".json"** file so I can’t tell how many vertices that model has.

My model by comparison has **4,832 Vertices** - which by the way, was listed in the "low-poly" category where I found it, so it's not really considered particularly big.
In terms of file-size, it's exactly `222kb.`
I tried scaling it down in Blender and re-exporting it - still came out at `222kb.`

Obviously I can take some “drastic measures”, like:
-Try to re-design my 3D model and make it smaller - but that would greatly reduce it’s beauty and the overall aesthetics of the project
-I can re-imagine or re-architect the project to display maybe 1,000 models at the same time instead of 3,000

etc.

But being that I’m new to THREE.js - and 3D modeling in general, I just wanted to first ask the community if there are any suggestions or tricks to try out first before making such radical changes.

-The model I'm importing is in the `.glTF` format - is that the best format to use or should I try something else?
-All the meshes in it come into the browser as instances of `BufferGeometry` which I believe is the lightest in terms of memory demands - is that correct?

Are there any other things I need to be aware of to optimize performance?
Some setting in `Blender` or other 3D modeling software that can reduce model-size?
Some general rules of thumb to follow when embarking on something like this?

Would really appreciate any and all help.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

GLTF is fine to transmit geometry and materials — I might say the standard right now. If there's only geometry, I'd see OBJ or PLY formats.

The model size is blocking, but only for the initial load if we employ [instancing](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/objects/InstancedMesh) on its geometry and material. This way we simply re-use the already generated geometry and its material.

> At the GPU level, instancing means drawing a single mesh with a single material shader, many times. You can override certain inputs to the material for each instance, but it sort of has to be a single material.

— [Don McCurdy](https://spectrum.chat/react-three-fiber/general/is-it-possible-for-each-instance-to-have-different-marterial-on-instancedmesh%7E16440e3f-071a-4bd7-9688-3a844bfeefff)

Our biggest worry here would be the triangles or faces rendered. Lower counts of this are more performant, and thus, fewer models at a time are. For this, you can use some degree of [LOD](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/objects/LOD) to progressively increase and decrease your models' detail until you stop rendering them at a distance.

Some examples/resources to get you started:

- [LOD](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_lod)
- [Instancing Models](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_instancing_scatter)
- [Modifying Instances](https://codesandbox.io/s/instancing-three-joy19)